# Ubuntu Touch AppArmor Kernel Patches

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-touch, apparmor, porting

new to Ubuntu development: I am porting Ubuntu touch to my own device.  There are many different commits related to AppArmor on 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/porting-new-device/#anchor4

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=ubuntu/ubuntu-utopic.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/mako

What would be a reasonably efficient way of applying these patches to the kernel source code I have stored locally.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

These [wiki instructions](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/AppArmorForPhabletKernels) go over how to backport the necessary apparmor changes.